# What is the meaning of "lure of the road"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **Fossil fuels stand for prosperity and freedom—from the romance of the roughneck to *"the lure of the road"*.**

I've looked up the *lure* in the dictionary and there were 3 entries

> 1
>   :  an object usually of leather or feathers attached to a long cord and used by a falconer to recall or exercise a hawk
>
> 2
>   a :  an inducement to pleasure or gain :  enticement
>   b :  appeal, attraction
>
> 3
>   :  a decoy for attracting animals to capture: as
>   a :  artificial bait used for catching fish
>   b :  an often luminous structure on the head of pediculate fishes that is used to attract prey

I guess ,in this case, the entry 2 fits in the sentence thus I interpreted this as.

> **"the lure of the road"="the pleasure of the road"**

Even though the entry 2 says it means **"attraction"** or "**encouragement**", I think it could also contain the meaning of **"pleasure"**. 
So, can fossil fuels both represent the romance of roughneck and the pleasure of constructing the road that is made of oil, which is very prosperous and liberal at the same time?

the link:
http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21710807-or-without-america-self-interest-will-sustain-fight-against-global-warming-climate

Comment: Not *constructing* the road, but *driving* on it, taking it somewhere.  The exciting prospect of being free to travel the country and go where you please, to find adventure and to leave responsibilities behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If google serves, the line in question is from a recent article in The Economist, titled "Climate Change in the era of Trump", and a look at the sentence within the context of the article clears things up somewhat.

> Plenty of Mr Trump’s voters dismiss climate change itself as a phoney
>   fad peddled by “bicoastal elites”. Fossil fuels stand for prosperity
>   and freedom — from the romance of the roughneck to the lure of the
>   road. Sure enough, on November 21st Mr Trump pledged that on day one
>   of his administration he would scrap “job-killing restrictions” on the
>   production of American fossil fuels, which account for 80% of
>   America’s man-made greenhouse-gas emissions.

*"Fossil fuels stand for prosperity and freedom"* - the article is discussing what fossil fuels represent to Trump's voters, and 'prosperity and freedom' straight away implies that these traits are seen to be positive traits. Which are:

- *the romance of the roughneck*

roughneck is a slang term for someone who works on an oil rig

- *the lure of the road.*

using the definitions you found, 'appeal' and 'attraction' seem to be by far the most appropriate synonyms - the *appeal* of being on the open road. Looking at it in the same positive light as the article, it conjures up the image of freedom, being able to go where you please, not being tied down to one place - all made possible by fossil fuel.

So yes, in this case I would say it means 'the attraction of the road' or 'the appeal of the road'.